# JSON file content validation

Tags: json, validation

I have a requirement where I get the data in a json file.
I need to validate the data inside the json file i.e. need to validate the content.

I have searched on the web but of no use.

How can I do validation of json file content ?
Can anybody help me in this regard , i.e. is it possible , if yes how to go about it ?

Thank you.
~Shyam

Comment: You should specify the teqnology you use, expected input/output, your effort taken (except googling for direct solution)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
try{
   var b =  $.parseJSON(yourJsonString)
    if(b){
     //valid josn
    }
}catch(e){
     console.log("error parsing.")
     //invalid json
}
```

Comment: My intention is not validate the json file rather its data/content. Need to develop such capability in my research project...any suggestion in this direction ? thank u.